# Copiar imagen del Web browser control y mostrarla en un Image control en wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Muy buenas comunidad estoy desarrollando una aplicación y tengo con este problema que no he podido solucionar, espero me puedan ayudar.

Mi necesidad es copiar una imagen de captcha de mi WebBrowser control al Clipboard y mostrarla en un Image control, pero no me muestra nada. Mi código es el siguiente y no presenta error alguno.

```
 //Navegacion del WebBrowser
 private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        wb.Navigate("https://portalcfdi.facturaelectronica.sat.gob.mx/");
    }


  private void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.captcha();
    }


 private void captcha() {

      mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)wb.Document; 

      mshtml.IHTMLControlRange imgRng = (mshtml.IHTMLControlRange)((mshtml.HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

        foreach (IHTMLElement elemento in doc.images)
        {
            string ruta = elemento.getAttribute("src");                
            if (ruta.Contains("/jcaptcha.jpg"))
            {
                imgRng.add((mshtml.IHTMLControlElement)elemento);
                imgRng.execCommand("Copy", false, null);                    

                if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
                {
                    imgC.Source = Clipboard.GetImage();
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Depuraste este codigo? copia algo en algun momento? porque vos estas copiando al clipboard, todo lo que cumple cierta condicion, no solo una imagen.

Comment: Que tal gbianchi

Comment: Que tal gbianchi 
¿Depuraste este codigo? El codigo lo depure y no marca ningun error todo esta muy bien.

¿Copia algo en algun momento? La imagen la copio mediante la instruccion  imgRng.execCommand("Copy", false, null); pero siendo sincero no se si copia dicha imagen del WebBrowser control.

¿porque estas copiando al clipboard? La imagen es un captcha por lo que al equivocarse esta se refresca es por ello que la copio al portapapeles para no descargarlas al equipo.

Comment: Me referia a si en algun momento, hay algo en el portapapeles. y no pregunte porque copiabas ahi, si no si estas seguro que no estas copiando multiples cosas una atras de la otra ahi. deberias ir paso a paso viendo que pasa y que tiene el portapapeles...

Comment: @SHINOBI Depurar el código significa muchas cosas, tienes muchísimas herramientas de depuración en el Visual Studio para poder ver en todo momento el estado de tu código. Por ejemplo puedes inspeccionar el contenido de tus variables o con la ventana de salida puedes ver mensajes que el compilador que son útiles. También depura tu código y pon un breakpoint justo después de la línea que hace el copiado al portapapeles, y comprueba que realmente el portapapeles tiene algún contenido.  Prueba a hacer esas cosas.

Comment: @Luis He depurado mi código y lo he modificado, ahora ya obtengo la imagen captcha pero esta imagen no es la misma que la que me muestra mi WebBrowser Control, Alguien sabe a que se debe.  Agradezco sus respuestas.